# Problema con desplegable seleccionable C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un `ComboBox` desplegable por llamarlo de alguna manera (`System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`) en el cual, simplemente invoco en el método de la clase para cargar los datos de la bd, la cosa es que tengo que añadir un campo para que me muestre todas las opciones que tiene el desplegable. Y no se muy bien como hacerlo.

```
public FormSumatorio()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<Tienda> t_list = Tiendas.getTiendas();

    foreach (Tienda t in t_list)
    {
        cBTiendas1.Items.Add(t);
    }
    cBTiendas1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    //cBUnidades.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Metodo getTiendas:

```
public static List<Tienda> getTiendas()
        {
            List<Tienda> tiendas = new List<Tienda>();

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM tiendas ";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql);
            MySqlDataReader reader = QueryPSDatabase(cmd);

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Tienda t = new Tienda();
                    t.id_store = reader.GetString("id_store");
                    t.ref_tienda = reader.GetString("ref_tienda");
                    t.id_country = reader.GetString("id_country");
                    t.id_state = reader.GetString("id_state");
                    t.name = reader.GetString("name");
                    t.address1 = reader.GetString("address1");
                    t.address2 = reader.GetString("address2");
                    t.city = reader.GetString("city");
                    t.postcode = reader.GetString("postcode");
                    t.transportista = reader.GetString("id_transportista");

                    tiendas.Add(t);
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            return tiendas;
        }
```

Tras obtener todas las tiendas, llamo al metodo clicando el boton, en el cual le paso el argumento de la tienda y me hace otra consulta a la bd para obtener todos los envios segun la tienda, con lo cual me gustaria tener una opcion que fuera para ver todo. Obviamente esta lista la incluyo en un datagrid.

Y el método que carga la info en el `ComboBox` simplemente hace la query a mysql y meto todo en una lista para mandárselo al form. Con lo cual quería saber como podría añadir yo una opción manualmente( ya con la consulta no tengo problema)

Gracias de antemano y saludos.

Comment: Te refieres a añadir un item al inicio que ponga "Seleccione opción" o algo asi?

Comment: Si, pero quiero que ponga TODAS y ver todo lo que sale, sin filtrar por nada

Comment: Creo que no termino de entenderte. un combobox de winforms no se filtra a priori, todas las opciones estan disponibles. Tal vez debas [edit] tu pregunta y poner algun ejemplo o imagen para aclararlo mas.

Comment: Me parece que quiere seleccionar un elemento que sea todos, y que eso le traiga todos... que es lo mismo que no seleccionar nada en el combo y no pasar una clausula where al query...:?

Comment: Creo haber entendido lo mismo que @gbianchi

Comment: Es posible @gbianchi, pero debería aclararlo yo creo. Y para eso el OP debería mostrar algo mas de código, por ejemplo que hace al seleccionar cada opción y la definición de la clase `Tienda`

Comment: Correcto, ando un poco espesito, yo en el combo box me trae una serie de opcion de la bd, con las que luego filtro la siguiente query, con lo cual quiero añadir una opcion que sea todos, sin que tenga ningun where y simplemente me muestre todos los datos, como lo hago mediante carga de listas, no se como añadirle al combo box el campo todos manualmente. Muchas gracias... Edito ahora la pregunta :)

Comment: Pero es innecesario eso.. por logica, siempre que no se selecciona nada en un combo vienen todos... poner un campo que diga todos, es como.. raro...

Comment: Añadir un item no tiene misterio. Simplemente, antes del bucle donde vas añadiendo las tiendas, pon un `cBTiendas1.Items.Add(new Tienda(){//aqui pones "TODOS" en el campo que se muestra en el combobox});` o algo asi, y luego en la consulta buscas ese texto. Pero como dice @gbianchi es un  comportamiento un poco extraño...

Comment: Como esta la clase.. puede agregar directo el string y tampoco pasa nada.. cBTiendas1.Items.Add("Todos");

Comment: Me valdria perfectamente dejarlo en blanco y que me devuelva todo, pero cuando abro el desplegable, no hay ese blanco, ya sale la primera opcion por defecto. De ahi mi pregunta, siento el lio

Comment: Porque no lo agregas antes o despues de llenar la lista? `cBTiendas1.Items.Add("Todos")`

Comment: Solucionado. Disculpar todo el embrollo, era tan simple como añadir todos y ya no filtra si no tiene la lógica. -.-'' postear la solución si queréis y os la doy por valida.

Answer (score 0):

yo lo haría así. Cualquier combo de este estilo implica que siempre el Index cero es Todos puedes mostrar un texto o bien dejarlo en blanco. Pero de esta forma sólo te basa en Index para determinar si has elegido una opción individual, es decir, Index > 1 o todos Index = 0:

```
public FormSumatorio()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<Tienda> t_list = Tiendas.getTiendas();
    // El primer elemento se usará para filtrado
    // de todos.
    cBTiendas1.Items.Add("(Todos)");
    // Resto de elementos llenamos el ComboBox
    foreach (Tienda t in t_list)
    {
        cBTiendas1.Items.Add(t);
    }
    // Index 0 significa TODOS
    cBTiendas1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```